# How to access a Gmail account

Tags: gmail

I have three emails one of them it seems has been deleted and I don't know why but the other two which all three were connected but the other two I can't get into because I don't have my old phone and I don't have the two step codes that I need to get into one of them so what application can I use to access my Gmail account

I've only tried on the Google site how to access these things and nothing has worked